# xslt: I need to concatenate two strings. The first string is a value from input xml file and second string should be "/"

Tags: xml, string, xslt, xslt-1.0, concatenation

I need to concatenate two strings in xslt.

What I tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="slash_id" select="/"/>
<xsl:variable name="prodname_id" select="$prodrev/@name"/>
<xsl:variable name="objstring_id" select="concat($prod_id,$slash_id)"/>
```

The variable value prodname_id is taken from input xml. I need suffix / to the prodname_id. So, I tried above way but didnt work.
If prodname_id is xyz then objstring_id should be xyz/

Can you help, how to achieve it. Do I need to use character set or CDATA for it. I am completely new to xslt. Please guide.

TIA

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you want to use:

```
<xsl:variable name="slash_id" select="'/'"/>
```

which selects the forward-slash character, instead of:

```
<xsl:variable name="slash_id" select="/"/>
```

which selects the entire input XML document.